# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'sitecore' of null

Tags: jss

I ran the `command jss start:react` , getting the error.

Error occured while trying to proxy to:

```
 localhost:3000/sitecore/api/jss/dictionary/myjssapp/en?sc_apikey=no-api-key-set.
```

I am working on a disconnected mode.

**My command prompt error**

```
D:\JSS-REACT-APP\myjssapp>jss start:react
> npm run start:react --

> myjssapp@12.0.0 start:react D:\JSS-REACT-APP\myjssapp
> react-scripts start

[HPM] Proxy created: /sitecore  ->  http://localhost:3042/
[HPM] Proxy created: /data/media  ->  http://localhost:3042/
Starting the development server...

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`
Compiled with warnings.

./src/components/YouTubeEmbed-Component/index.js
  Line 16:   elements must have a unique title property                                                        jsx-a11y/iframe-has-title
  Line 19:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /sitecore/api/jss/dictionary/myjssapp/en?sc_apikey=no-api-key-set from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3042/ (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=%2F&sc_lang=en&sc_apikey=no-api-key-set
```

Comment: Is the command to start in connected mode as - jss start:connected. Also please share the .html and .ts generated file for the YouTubeEmbed-Component

Comment: I am working on a disconnected mode, I removed this YouTubeEmbeded-Component, Still facing the prob "can not read the property 'sitecore' of null"

Comment: I can see in the developer console (504  Gateway timed out error)

Comment: 504 Gateway timed out error - Is the Sitecore Instance on Azure ?

Comment: its a disconnected mode development.....i am not using sitecore instance and also its not in Azure

Comment: Error occurred while trying to proxy request /sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=%2F&sc_lang=en&sc_apikey=no-api-key-set from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:

Comment: when are u getting the error?

Comment: from morning onwards....

Comment: Did you update the `disconnected-mode-proxy.js`?

Comment: i did not update anything

Comment: I meant which step are you getting the error , are you getting the error on jss deploy or jss start:connected . Now Since the error msg is not clear and code is not shared IMO Best option for you is to start over , create a new sample react app and move components step by step

Comment: @AbhayDhar No, This error was not coming while jss deploy, it was fully disconnected mode development. I did not deploy this app in the sitecore yet.

Now, i am moving my components in new created react app, because i am unable to resolve this issue.